# My Software Utilizing JPCAP Is Not running on 64 bit computers

Tags: java, jvm, jpcap

I have over the past week developed an software that makes use of the JPCAP library to sniff packets and detect spoofed IPs. Now I have finished making it and it works perfectly on my computer and other 32 bit computers, however, when i tried to install and run it on 64 bit computers, it doesnt work. It displays 'A JAVA EXCEPTION HAS OCCURRED'. Please does anyone know what exactly the problem is and how it can be solved. I am aware that JPCAP is quite problematic when it comes to its implementation on 64 bit computers.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13080151/903875) answer (I've no idea if you've come across it yet) suggests that someone managed to at least build a 64-bit version of the library that you could try using. Good luck!